# updating information from database - error db locked

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013, sqlite

I created an app like a quiz.. When I try to show the score in the labels I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll   Additional information: database is locked database is locked
```

I know which is the problem, but I don`t know how to solve it.
The problem is for sure in the Menu Form (the 'highest parent'). And I know that because the app updates the database from the Quiz form, but when it comes back and read the database so that I can change the labels I got that error. ONLY IF THE update_score() is both in Meniu() (or even in Meniu_Load() ) and after the .ShowDialog()

update_score() -reads database and change labels

Conclusion:  I can not show in labels the highest scores both times: when I open the app and when comes back from the quizz form..So, I have to put in comment the update_score after the showdialog (the user won`t know the score when it comes back) or in the Meniu /Meniu_Load (it does not show at the beginning).
How can I solve it?

The Menu code:

```
public partial class Meniu : Form
{
    SQLiteConnection con;
    public bool con_opened = false; // tin minte daca am deschis conexiunea
    public int bs_lit=0, bs_info = 0;

    public Meniu()
    {            
        //this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;            
        InitializeComponent();
        con_opened=false;
        update_score();   
    }
    private void Meniu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //con_opened=false;
        //update_score();

    } 

    public void db1_read()
    {
        if (con_opened == false)
        {
            con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");//Version=3;
            con_opened = true;
            con.Open();
        }

        string sql = "select * from bestscore WHERE materie LIKE 'literatura'";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        bs_lit = Int32.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
        command.Dispose();


        sql = "select * from bestscore WHERE materie LIKE 'informatica'";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        bs_info = Int32.Parse(rdr[1].ToString());
        cmd.Dispose();

        con.Close();
        con_opened = false;
    }       

    private void update_score()
    {
        db1_read();           
        lbl_bs_info.Text = bs_info.ToString();
        lbl_bs_lit.Text = bs_lit.ToString();            
    }





    private void btn_literatura_testare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testare flit = new testare();
        this.Hide();
        flit.reveal = false;
        flit.materie = "literatura";
        flit.ShowDialog();
        update_score(); // if the function is here and in Meniu()
        // or Meniu_load()I receive the error
           // if it`s just one of them
                 //it works just fine

        if (flit.reveal == true)
            this.Show();
        else
            Application.Exit();
    }      
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: make sure you don't run parallel connections

Comment: I would try closing the connection when you're done.

Comment: I really searched "parallel connections", because I use another form to create new questions and to read from database. but after every function I do a command.Dispose() and connection.Close()

Comment: I see no connection.Close() or con.Close()

Comment: I close the connection ..db_inchide() -> connection.close()

Comment: Do you have a new SQLiteConnection( anywhere else that you have open?

Comment: Yes. I have. In another form, where I read The data for both quizzes. It is probably other connection.. but how should I realize which one?

Comment: make sure you close or dispose it when done.
using (var con = new SqliteConnection()) could be a good option.
Probably what you really want to do is have a single long lived connection. but i'm not that familliar with sqlite.

Comment: After you said before.. I changed all other functions that call the database, so that I Dispose and Close connection every time. And don`t see how would be closing and opening connection a problem. I do it exactly to make sure that I close everything behind me.

Comment: It's always good to close things you open but that wasn't the problem.
This seams to have som info https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I didn`t Dispose the readers. Now it works.

```
public void db1_read()
    {
        if (con_opened == false)
        {
            con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");//Version=3;
            con_opened = true;
            con.Open();
        }

        string sql = "select * from bestscore WHERE materie LIKE 'literatura'";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        bs_lit = Int32.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
        command.Dispose();
        reader.Dispose();


        sql = "select * from bestscore WHERE materie LIKE 'informatica'";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rdr.Read();
        bs_info = Int32.Parse(rdr[1].ToString());
        cmd.Dispose();
        rdr.Dispose();

        con.Close();
        con_opened = false;
    }
```